# Percentile for Year-to-Day (successive YtD)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
ID |MPERIOD|FRDATE    |FR
===+=======+==========+==
100|2017M01|01.01.2017|60  \              \              \
101|2017M01|02.01.2017|75   > YtD 2017M01  |              |
103|2017M01|08.01.2017|48  /               > Ytd 2017M02  |
104|2017M02|06.02.2017|55                  |              > YtD 2017M03
105|2017M02|15.02.2017|63                 /               |
106|2017M03|18.03.2017|41                                 |
107|2017M03|22.03.2017|71                                /
...|.......|..........|..
```

I need to calculate 80% percentile for each month and for YtD in (up to) that month (from start of year up to current calculation moment).

I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mperiod,
   ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fr OVER (PARTITION BY mperiod),2) "80%_FR", 
   ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fr OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(mperiod,1,4)),2) "80%_FR_YtD" 
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 1
```

If I run this query in last day of month when I do not have data for the following month yet then this SQL will correctly calculate YtD value. For example, if I have data for first six months and do not have data for seventh month, and calculate this for sixth month then calculation with year partition `OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(mperiod,1,4)` will calculate correct YtD value. But if I have data after this month it will be included in PARTITION BY and will not calculate up to that moment.

How to calculate YtD retroactively, for previous months!? For example, the calculation of YtD for third month should include calculation for only those first three months in year, not all months in year.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use a windowing clause or add in additional order by columns in PERCENTILE_CONT (boo!), here's one way of achieving your aims. N.B. it's not pretty, and I'm sure it won't be terrifically performant, but it should work at least!

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT 100 ID, '2017M01' mperiod, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 60 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 101 ID, '2017M01' mperiod, to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 75 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 103 ID, '2017M01' mperiod, to_date('08/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 48 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 104 ID, '2017M02' mperiod, to_date('06/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 55 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 105 ID, '2017M02' mperiod, to_date('15/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 63 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 106 ID, '2017M03' mperiod, to_date('18/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 41 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 107 ID, '2017M03' mperiod, to_date('22/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 71 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 108 ID, '2016M12' mperiod, to_date('22/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 42 fr FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 109 ID, '2016M11' mperiod, to_date('22/11/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') frdate, 32 fr FROM dual),
      unpckd AS (SELECT mt.ID,
                        mt.mperiod,
                        mt.frdate,
                        mt.fr,
                        CASE WHEN substr(mt.mperiod, -2) <= d.id THEN SUBSTR(mt.mperiod, 1, 5) || to_char(d.id, 'fm09')
                        END  new_mperiod,
                        d.id dummy_id
                 FROM   mytable mt
                        INNER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL ID
                                    FROM   dual
                                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) d ON substr(mt.mperiod, -2) <= d.id),
         res AS (SELECT mperiod,
                        new_mperiod,
                        ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fr) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN mperiod = new_mperiod THEN mperiod END),2) fr_80, 
                        ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fr) OVER (PARTITION BY new_mperiod),2) fr_80_ytd
                 FROM unpckd)
SELECT DISTINCT new_mperiod mperiod,
                fr_80 "80%_FR",
                fr_80_ytd "80%_FR_YtD"
FROM   res
WHERE  new_mperiod = mperiod
ORDER BY 1;

MPERIOD      80%_FR 80%_FR_YtD
-------- ---------- ----------
2016M11          32         32
2016M12          42         40
2017M01          69         69
2017M02        61.4       65.4
2017M03          65       69.4
```

This works by doing a partial cross join between the numbers 1 to 12 (12 months in the year) and the last two digits of the mperiod. Once we have that, we now know the overall ytd period that the rows belong to (ie. number 1 will match to the 2017M01, 2 will match to 2017M01 and 2017M02, etc), so you can now produce a label for this calculated value (which I've called new_mperiod) and use that to partition against.

It's obviously going to be inefficient (since the partial cross join will generate more rows than is necessary for a year that's not got data for all its months, which get filtered out later, but I can't think of a better way of doing it.